# How to find similar items other users liked

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science

I've a book dataset:

```
ratings.head()

    User-ID     ISBN    Book-Rating
0   276725  034545104X  0
1   276726  0155061224  5
2   276727  0446520802  0
3   276729  052165615X  3
4   276729  0521795028  6
```

and I want to find recommendations to a particular book. In other words, I want to to find users who rated that book high and see what other books they rated high too.

I've tried:

```
data_p = pd.pivot_table(ratings, index='User-ID', columns='ISBN', values='Book-Rating')

def recommend(isbn):
    user_ratings = data_p[isbn]
    liked_target = user_ratings[user_ratings > 9] # This is wrong I think
    similar_to_target = data_p.corrwith(liked_target)
    corr_target = pd.DataFrame(similar_to_target, columns = ['Correlation'])
    corr_target = corr_target.sort_values('Correlation', ascending = False)
    return corr_target.head(15)

recommend("0345339703") # Lord of the Rings: Fellowship of the Ring
```

but I think I'm missing there the "who liked" (say who rated 10) element in the code. Also, I'd like to introduce some weighted measure, so two people who liked some book 8 are more valid than one who rated another book 9.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: you may want to look at  `df.pivot_table(index='User-ID',columns='ISBN',values='Book-Rating',aggfunc='first')` ?

Comment: @anky_91 What does the aggfunc='first' do?

Comment: what i mean is this will give you a view per user about the rating of books(ISBN). Since you haven't provided an expected output,i thought of this, please try on the sample data and let me know

Comment: You should add an expected output to your code with an appropriate sample input.